# Using enums as key in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have enum which looks like this

```
enum DialogBar {
    None = 'none',
    Jira = 'jira',
    Kisi = 'kisi',
    Greenhouse = 'greenhouse',
}
```

if I do something like this

```
if (DialogBar[serviceName]) {
 setDialogBarOpen(DialogBar[serviceName]);
}
```

it throws error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof DialogBar'.
```

```
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof DialogBar'
```

When I `console.log` DialogBar, I see this.

```
{
    "None": "none",
    "Jira": "jira",
    "Kisi": "kisi",
    "Greenhouse": "greenhouse"
}
```

Also, if someone could suggest some clean alternate?

Comment: `let serviceName: keyof DialogBar ` (but you should maube use `Record<DialogBar, whatever>` instear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TS won't allow you to index an object using a string as a key.. Unless you tell it to:

```js
const serviceName: string = "Jira";

if (DialogBar[serviceName as keyof typeof DialogBar]) {
    console.log(DialogBar[serviceName as keyof typeof DialogBar]);
    // -> 'jira'
}
```

I think this way is already cleaner and explicit.
[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAIglgQwDYHsDmAhBAnKBvAKCmKgDkURgoBeKAchAuDoBoiSApObBG+gK24JW7YgGk4AZzh86AaylwRJKAHFswUAAsUYSVVp00G7bv0iAvgQIBjCpIAuUfdgBucG8FIIIwAFzODthwIGh8AERcPOEA3NZwAGZQABTwyOhY2ADaLu6e3r5QCJJQcsAAnihJDuUADsBVsIiomDgAugCU+KJQdiCSKEjAAHQtqc0ZODnAbh5ePlTFpRWNNfWNaS2ZnXFWQA)